# svg data gives error for texture on canvg translate

Tags: three.js

I get the error when the animate() loop starts:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:8080/threejs_1/%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

and not sure what threejs is looking for on the server. The svg data begins:

```
<svg style="width: 512px; height: 512px;" id="ext-gen2256" height="512" width="512"
version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs></defs><rect id="ext-gen2257"
opacity="0" stroke="none" fill="#000" height="100%" width="100%"></rect><path
transform="matrix(1,0,0, ... </svg>

var SvgData = Ext.DomQuery.selectNode('svg', 'div11').parentNode.innerHTML;
var imageCanvas22 = document.createElement("canvas");
canvg(imageCanvas22, SvgData);
var texture33 = new THREE.Texture(imageCanvas22);
texture33.needsUpdate = true;
map = THREE3.ImageUtils.loadTexture( texture33 ); // is this correct usage ???
// map = THREE3.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/teechart-bar2.png" ); // works
map.wrapS = map.wrapT = THREE3.RepeatWrapping;
map.repeat.set( 16, 16 );
var planeGeo = new THREE3.PlaneGeometry( 200, 200 );
ground = new THREE3.Mesh( planeGeo, new THREE3.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff,   ambient: 0xffffff, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 50, map: map, perPixel: true, metal: true } ) );
ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
scene.add( ground );
```

On inspection the texture looks ok and the map looks ok. Not sure where to start on this on. The scene does render and work properly but the ground has no texture applied. When the texture is loaded from file everything functions correctly. Would posting the complete svg help?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this from here

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1305

It was not the correct usage:

```
// map = THREE3.ImageUtils.loadTexture( texture33 );
map =  texture33 ;
```